# How to access a Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding via an insertNewline event in Ember.TextField?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to access a Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding on an insertNewline event in Ember.TextField.

What is the best way to do this? 
In my broken attempt, ArtistsIsChecked always returns false.

See this fiddle for complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/jdcravens/T24ej/

```
App.SearchBox = Em.TextField.extend({
  insertNewline: function() {
    var query = this.get('value');
      if (this.container.lookup('controller:application').get('ArtistsIsChecked')){
          this.container.lookup('controller:artists').search(query);
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

**Lowercase property names**

The bindings for the checkboxes were not working correctly because the first letter of the property needs to be lowercase:

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="artistsIsChecked"}}
```

**Referencing the parent controller from a component**

[Components](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/), such as a `TextField`, don't directly have the context of their parent controller/view. You can get a reference to the parent controller by accessing the `targetObject` property.

```
controller = this.get('targetObject'); // the parent controller
```

this lets you access properties/methods of the parent controller without using the container.

**Accessing other controllers from a controller**

Also, instead of using the container to access other controllers, you should use the [needs 
system](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

```
App.ApplicationController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['artists'],
    ....
})
```

and can be accessed by accessing a controller's `controllers` property:

```
var artistsController = this.get('controllers.artists');
```

**Use the new style for inputs**

You should also probably switch to using the new style of [inputs, `{{input ... }}`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_input) instead of directly using the `{{view}}` helper.

[updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T24ej/15/)